# SharePoint 2013 - Infopath form on subsite, referencing list on root site

Tags: infopath, sub-site

I have a list with an InfoPath form on my root site level. I've created a subsite, and would like to move the InfoPath form from the root site to this subsite (while leaving the actual list on the root site). Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how it should be approached?

I've tried editing my InfoPath form page and exporting the InfoPath Web Part, but after adding this Web Part to my subsite I found that all of the list/form info was lost. I have not yet tried saving the template as an App and then adding this App to my subsite because I'm still working on getting the necessary security permissions to do such, but I'm skeptical that this will work either because when adding this App back onto my root site (for testing purposes) it only surfaced a new list (from the template) instead of adding the form, and so my connection to the original list was lost.

Thanks!

Comment: I am also trying to do the same thing... just wondering if there is any update on this thread. Any recommendation is appreciated. Thanks